# Shared memory and strings: managed?

Tags: string, boost, managed, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I have a problem with `boost::interprocess::string` in shared memory.

When I use a `shared_memory_object` I can manipulate a structure with different fields, BUT strings (I get a segmentation fault).
On the other side, when I use `managed_shared_memory` everything is fine.

Am I doing something wrong? Do you know if there is a performance penalty using `managed_shared_memory`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using strings in boost interprocess, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278627/c-boostinterprocess-simple-application/4540790#4540790).

As for performance, it should be better than most other solution - this is the reason it exists - to share memory between processes. Every other method to share data between process would have an overhead that shared memory don't need (packet header + IO for TCP, DB round trips for DB, etc.)